# Why I got error with image/intervention after I moved laravel site under docker?

Tags: laravel, docker, intervention

I moved laravel site under docker(based on php:8.1.6-apache) under my local ubuntu 20
and I use medialibrary and intervention for images controlling, but I got unexpected error :

```
Unable to init from given url
```

on line of code where I try to get properties of an image :

```
$currencyMedia = $this->getFirstMedia(config('app.media_app_name'));

if ( ! empty($currencyMedia) and File::exists($currencyMedia->getPath())) {
    $currencyImage['url']        = $currencyMedia->getUrl();
    $imageInstance              = Image::load($currencyMedia->getUrl());
    \Log::info( ' $imageInstance::');
    \Log::info( print_r($imageInstance, true) ); // I check what is in $imageInstance

    $currencyImage['width']      = $imageInstance->getWidth(); // I got error on this line
    $currencyImage['height']     = $imageInstance->getHeight();
```

In log file I see :

```
 local.INFO:  $imageInstance::
 local.INFO: Spatie\Image\Image Object
(
    [manipulations:protected] => Spatie\Image\Manipulations Object
        (
            [manipulationSequence:protected] => Spatie\Image\ManipulationSequence Object
                (
                    [groups:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [imageDriver:protected] => gd
    [temporaryDirectory:protected] =>
    [optimizerChain:protected] =>
    [pathToImage:protected] => http://127.0.0.1:8088/storage/currency_app/31/brazilian_cruzeiro.png
)
```

In browser I can open valid image in browser by copypasting.
Full error log :

```
[2022-10-18 15:58:31] local.ERROR: Unable to init from given url (http://127.0.0.1:8088/storage/currency_app/31/brazilian_cruzeiro.png). {"userId":1,"exception":"[object] (Intervention\\Image\\Exception\\NotReadableException(code: 0): Unable to init from given url (http://127.0.0.1:8088/storage/currency_app/31/brazilian_cruzeiro.png). at /ProjectPath/vendor/intervention/image/src/Intervention/Image/AbstractDecoder.php:85)
[stacktrace]
#0 /ProjectPath/vendor/intervention/image/src/Intervention/Image/AbstractDecoder.php(335): Intervention\\Image\\AbstractDecoder->initFromUrl('http://127.0.0....')
#1 /ProjectPath/vendor/intervention/image/src/Intervention/Image/AbstractDriver.php(66): Intervention\\Image\\AbstractDecoder->init('http://127.0.0....')
#2 /ProjectPath/vendor/intervention/image/src/Intervention/Image/ImageManager.php(54): Intervention\\Image\\AbstractDriver->init('http://127.0.0....')
#3 /ProjectPath/vendor/intervention/image/src/Intervention/Image/ImageManagerStatic.php(58): Intervention\\Image\\ImageManager->make('http://127.0.0....')
#4 /ProjectPath/vendor/spatie/image/src/Image.php(93): Intervention\\Image\\ImageManagerStatic::make('http://127.0.0....')
#5 /ProjectPath/app/Http/Resources/CurrencyResource.php(45): Spatie\\Image\\Image->getWidth()
#6 /ProjectPath/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Collections/HigherOrderCollectionProxy.php(60): App\\Http\\Resources\\CurrencyResource->toArray(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#7 [internal function]: Illuminate\\Support\\HigherOrderCollectionProxy->Illuminate\\Support\\{closure}(Object(App\\Http\\Resources\\CurrencyResource), 1)
```

Also I run

```
php artisan storage:link
```

under docker box.

Why this error and how it can be fixed?
When the app was hosted under hosting ubuntu 20 it worked ok...

```
"laravel/framework": "^v9.6.0",
"spatie/laravel-medialibrary": "^10.0.0",
"intervention/image": "^2.7",
```

**UPDATED INFO :**

Yes, I have both imagick and gd installed and enabled. My Dockerfile.yml :

```
  FROM php:8.1.6-apache
    RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install --assume-yes --no-install-recommends --quiet \
    python \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    libwebp-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    libzip-dev \
    nano \
    mc \
    git-core \
    libmagickwand-dev \
    curl \
    build-essential \
    libnotify-bin \
    openssl \
    libssl-dev \
    libgmp-dev \
    libldap2-dev \
    netcat \
    locate \
    && git clone https://github.com/nodejs/node.git && \
    cd node  \
    && git checkout v14.18.0 \
    && ./configure \
    && make \
    && make install

  RUN pecl install imagick \
    && docker-php-ext-enable imagick

    RUN npm install cross-env

    RUN npm install -g yarn

    RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg --with-webp  --with-jpeg

     RUN docker-php-ext-install gd


    RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

    RUN  docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql zip gmp bcmath pcntl ldap sysvmsg exif  \
    && a2enmod rewrite

    RUN apt-get install -y grep mlocate

    COPY virtualhost.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf
```

Also looking in output of php info :

```
imagick
imagick module  enabled
imagick module version  3.7.0
imagick classes Imagick, ImagickDraw, ImagickPixel, ImagickPixelIterator, ImagickKernel
Imagick compiled with ImageMagick version   ImageMagick 6.9.11-60 Q16 x86_64 2021-01-25 https://imagemagick.org
Imagick using ImageMagick library version   ImageMagick 6.9.11-60 Q16 x86_64 2021-01-25 https://imagemagick.org
ImageMagick copyright   (C) 1999-2021 ImageMagick Studio LLC
ImageMagick release date    2021-01-25
ImageMagick number of supported formats:    247
ImageMagick supported formats   3FR, 3G2, 3GP, AAI, AI, APNG, ART, ARW, AVI, AVIF, AVS, BGR, BGRA, BGRO, BIE, BMP, BMP2, BMP3, BRF, CAL, CALS, CANVAS, CAPTION, CIN, CIP, CLIP, CMYK, CMYKA, CR2, CR3, CRW, CUR, CUT, DATA, DCM, DCR, DCX, DDS, DFONT, DJVU, DNG, DOT, DPX, DXT1, DXT5, EPDF, EPI, EPS, EPS2, EPS3, EPSF, EPSI, EPT, EPT2, EPT3, ERF, EXR, FAX, FILE, FITS, FRACTAL, FTP, FTS, G3, G4, GIF, GIF87, GRADIENT, GRAY, GRAYA, GROUP4, GV, H, HALD, HDR, HEIC, HISTOGRAM, HRZ, HTM, HTML, HTTP, HTTPS, ICB, ICO, ICON, IIQ, INFO, INLINE, IPL, ISOBRL, ISOBRL6, J2C, J2K, JBG, JBIG, JNG, JNX, JP2, JPC, JPE, JPEG, JPG, JPM, JPS, JPT, JSON, K25, KDC, LABEL, M2V, M4V, MAC, MAGICK, MAP, MASK, MAT, MATTE, MEF, MIFF, MKV, MNG, MONO, MOV, MP4, MPC, MPG, MRW, MSL, MSVG, MTV, MVG, NEF, NRW, NULL, ORF, OTB, OTF, PAL, PALM, PAM, PANGO, PATTERN, PBM, PCD, PCDS, PCL, PCT, PCX, PDB, PDF, PDFA, PEF, PES, PFA, PFB, PFM, PGM, PGX, PICON, PICT, PIX, PJPEG, PLASMA, PNG, PNG00, PNG24, PNG32, PNG48, PNG64, PNG8, PNM, POCKETMOD, PPM, PREVIEW, PS, PS2, PS3, PSB, PSD, PTIF, PWP, RADIAL-GRADIENT, RAF, RAS, RAW, RGB, RGBA, RGBO, RGF, RLA, RLE, RMF, RW2, SCR, SCT, SFW, SGI, SHTML, SIX, SIXEL, SPARSE-COLOR, SR2, SRF, STEGANO, SUN, SVG, SVGZ, TEXT, TGA, THUMBNAIL, TIFF, TIFF64, TILE, TIM, TTC, TTF, TXT, UBRL, UBRL6, UIL, UYVY, VDA, VICAR, VID, VIDEO, VIFF, VIPS, VST, WBMP, WEBM, WEBP, WMF, WMV, WMZ, WPG, X, X3F, XBM, XC, XCF, XPM, XPS, XV, XWD, YCbCr, YCbCrA, YUV
```

and :

```
gd
GD Support  enabled
GD Version  bundled (2.1.0 compatible)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think its a docker problem, do you have imagic installed and working for docker?

Comment: Could you please share the Dockerfile, My initial assumption is there is something to do with port mapping and host IP.

Comment: Please read UPDATED INFO